# Reference kotlin-js resources from kotlin-jvm in Kotlin 1.3 multiplatform gradle project

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

In Kotlin 1.2.61 it was possible to have a Gradle dependency from a kotlin-jvm module to a kotlin-js module.

This is useful for including the generated js files in a self-contained jar to serve them as static resources.

However, as of Kotlin 1.2.70 there is a restriction that prevents adding a dependency from a kotlin-jvm module to a kotlin-js module, see: [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-26834).

What is the supported way to make sure that a kotlin-js module gets built before the a kotlin-jvm module, so that the kotlin-js dist files can be included in the kotlin-jvm module (presumably without adding a dependency between them)?

Answer (score 1):

Answering own question, turns out that the Kotlin frontend plugin is deprecated, and the supported solution is to use the Multiplatform plugin.

I was able to get it working with Kotlin Gradle DSL, with a Spring Boot back-end (including being able to debug from IDE) and hot-reload of React front-end:
https://github.com/alexoooo/sample-multiplatform-boot-react

The proj-jvm build.gradle.kts declares a dependency on the proj-js module:

```
tasks.withType<ProcessResources> {
    val jsProject = project(":proj-js")
    val task = jsProject.tasks.getByName("browserProductionWebpack") as KotlinWebpack

    from(task.destinationDirectory!!) {
        into("public")
    }

    dependsOn(task)
}
```

Note that Kotlin multiplatform projects are currently experimental, and some of the details are likely to change as the new IR is introduced: https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2020/03/kotlin-1-4-m1-released/